# v-model number, запретить ввод отрицательных значений

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Есть инпут с v-model в котором прописывается количество товаров. Требуется ограничить ввод отрицательных значений в инпут с клавиатуры, min="1" не помогает. Также пробовал в мутации указать условие, все равно не помогло, подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

```
 <input
      class="quantity-value text-right"
      name="inputQuantity"
      v-model.number="cart_item_data.quantity"
      @input="updateItem"
      min="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил путем указания else в мутации, теперь минимальное значение всегда будет 1 даже если попытаться ввести отриц значения

```
UPDATE(state, index) {
  if(state.cart[index].quantity > 1) {
     state.cart[index].quantity
  }
  else {
    state.cart[index].quantity = 1
  }
},
```